# Devart T4 Editor 1.0.9 fails to install for VS 2017 Pro

Tags: t4, devart

I've successfully installed this on another machine. Do you see what I need to do on my machine to get this installed? Here's the install log:

```
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - -------------------------------------------
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - 15.0.437+g8d2477ee3d
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - -------------------------------------------
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - Command line parameters:
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Devart.TemplateEditor.Vs2017.vsix
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - -------------------------------------------
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
5/24/2018 9:55:57 AM - -------------------------------------------
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - Initializing Install...
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - Extension Details...
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  Identifier         : T4 Editor
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  Name               : Devart T4 Editor
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  Author             : Devart
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  Version            : 1.0.9.0
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  Description        : Editor for T4 and Devart template files with syntax coloring and IntelliSense.
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  Locale             : en-US
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  MoreInfoURL        : http://www.devart.com/
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  InstalledByMSI     : False
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - 
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  SignatureState     : Unsigned
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  Supported Products : 
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -          Version : [15.0]
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - 
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  References         : 
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  Prerequisites      : 
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -      -------------------------------------------------------
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -      Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -      Name         : Visual Studio core editor
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -      Version      : [15.0,16.0)
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - 
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - Signature Details...
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM -  Extension is not signed.
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - 
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - Searching for applicable products...
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 (2)
5/24/2018 9:55:59 AM - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.EngineUtilities.TryGetProductVersion(String productVersionString, Version& productVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.EngineUtilities.TryGetProductVersionFromPath(String path, Version& productVersion)
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedVSSKU.get_VersionWithBuildRevisionInfo()
   at VSIXInstaller.App.IsValidSKUForExtension(SupportedVSSKU supportedSKU, IExtension extension, List`1 validSKUs)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.ShouldAddSkuToValidSkuList(SupportedVSSKU sku, IInstallableExtension extension, List`1 validSKUs)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, Boolean isRepairSupported, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: you only have Build tools installed, no real SKU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are installing [T4 Editor for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.devart.com/t4-editor/Devart.TemplateEditor.Vs2017.vsix), aren't you?
2. Is Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 installed on your workstation? Refer to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/32018/vsixinstallerexe-cant-install-extensions-when-visu.html.
3. Open your VS 2017 Professional > Help > Check for Updates. Apply updates if any. Does this help?

Comment: 1) Yes, 2)  Yes, and that reference may have been the issue, 3) Yes, it did help. I had to both update the VS Build Tools and 2017. One or both fixed the issue. Thank you for taking your time to help here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @magicandre1981 for the hint.

I have VS 2017 pro installed. I took a look at the error log that results from trying to install T4 editor for VS 2015. The supported product list is more inclusive for T4 editor for VS2015:

```
5/25/2018 9:29:53 AM -  Supported Products : 
5/25/2018 9:29:53 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
5/25/2018 9:29:53 AM -          Version : [14.0]
5/25/2018 9:29:53 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.VST_All
5/25/2018 9:29:53 AM -          Version : [14.0]
```

The installer is looking for only the community SKU for VS 2017. This appears to be the issue here.